# Make all elements of a CSS class act as a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

I am using Squarespace to make a bilingual site.

The company logo in the nav bar is set through a Squarespace panel. I managed to override the default english logo by inserting the following code into the header:

```
<style> h1.logo { content: url("url_of_french_logo");} </style>
```

This works to change the logo from english to french, however it loses the hyperlink back to the homepage (i.e. it is just an image and is not clickable).

Is there a way to make this link to the french homepage? It is the only item of this class (h1.logo) on the page.

PS - I have no access to the source code. All I can do is add code to the header, or somewhere on the page (as a code block).

Comment: Use JS to wrap the element inside an `a` tag

Comment: This sounds like a great solution. Can you give me the code to do this, including how I would make sure that only that link points to my french homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener based on you `h1.logo` query,
and use the function

```
location.href = URL
```

`URL` being your desire destination adn should looks like this "http://google.com"

Hope this helps :)

```js
var logo = document.querySelectorAll('h1.logo');
logo[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.href = URL;
})
```

```html
<h1 class="logo">Click me</h1>
```

Comment: and do use the double quoute

Comment: Do you have a live view

Comment: Putting your script in the page (so that it was after the sqs script) worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, dont forget to upvote if you can. Thak you

Comment: Wish I could - not enough rep unfortunately.

Comment: No worries, glad to help